# Advance on getting information from a menu

Tags: python, menu

This is my entire code: https://github.com/samy-b/Assignment1/blob/main/addressbook

The main bit I am struggerling with is line 45. We have to create a function that will ask the user to enter the first letter of the surname of a person. Once the user has entered the letter then the program will display all of the attributes such firstname, lastname, address and phone number related to that letter. What can I use to make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after the user input the letter, make the program iterate through the keys of the `info` dictionary, using the subscription of `[1]` to get the Surname element of each list, and the subscription of `[0]` to get the first character of each surname:

```
      elif user_input == 3:
         firstletter = input("Please enter the first letter of their Surname")
         for line in info:
             if info[line][1][0] == firstletter:
                 print(info[line])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of all surnames starting with what you typed:

```
list(filter(lambda u: u[1].startswith(firstletter), user_info))
```